# Add RAM to my desktop

Tags: memory, upgrade

I've never added RAM to my desktop PC yet.
It has an Intel e5700 processor, and currently has 2GB of DDR3 RAM. 
Also it is 32-bit Windows 7.

Am I right in thinking I can just buy some extra RAM, say an extra 2GB, or 4GB and open up the PC and slide the RAM card into the correct slot, boot up the machine and then I have a faster, sleeker machine? Sounds too easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is easy, as long as you get the correct memory.

Use [Crucial System Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/) to find what memory you need. Motherboard model would help, cpu does not matter. And since the system is only 32bit your max memory will be only 4gb.

Answer (score 1):

That is about all there is too it.

Ensure that ram speeds are [compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) (ex 1066MHz or 1333MHz), and you shouldn't have any issues. If you have upgraded other components around the same time, you may have to face [Windows reactivation](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/i-cannot-activate-my-windows-key-after-hardware/baa19f2f-5c19-4c6e-bb73-863749864ff2) through telephone.

Comment: My computer says this about the processor: Pentium Dual Core CPU, E5700 @3.00GHz 3.00GHz. What does this mean?

Comment: Typically, the motherboard bus is the determining factor in compatible ram speeds. So your processor speed/model has little to do with selection of ram compared to your motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds easy but it is possible that all available slots on the motherboard are already taken.  In this case, you will need to decide which one you want to replace with the new memory.

The e5700 processor is a 64-bit processor but you are running a 32 bit operating system.  The most a 32 bit operating system can use is just over 4gb but about .5gb of that memory allocation is used by the graphics card and other items.  In my experience only 3.5gb is usable on a 32bit system.

It might be useful to download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/) and see what the timings are on your current memory so you can select new memory with the same timings.

Answer (score 0):

As long as everything supports it, and you have an extra slot, then you are right in thinking that as far as my experience goes.

There is a good chance that you will see an immediate performance increase, especially if you do any gaming/video watching.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the memory cards into the extra slots your computer might have. You'll need to make sure that your computer recognises the memory cards, though.